# Populating a table in R

Tags: r, populate, confidence-interval

I am attempting to make a table that would hold the sample size determination from several methods for different initial probabilities. I would like it to look something like the following

```
Prob.    .80    .81    .82 ...
Wald     xxx    yyy    zzz
AC       qqq    rrr    sss
Jeff.    ddd    uuu    iii
```

With the letters being the actual output I would like to populate with based on the type of interval and the probability value. In order to get an individual value I could use the following pieces of code, but am struggling to put them together.

```
library(binom)
n_wald <- ciss.wald(p, d, alpha = a)
n_agricoull <- ciss.agresticoull(p, d, alpha = a)
n_jeffreys <- ciss.binom(p, d, alpha = a, prior.shape1 = 0.5,
 prior.shape2 = 0.5, method = "bayes")
```

I want help in converting the sample size calculations into a table for each increment of initial probability. Basically, I am trying to use the second piece of code to fill in the "xxx" for the table.

Comment: So... what, specifically, is your question?

Comment: @Alex I want help in converting the sample size calculations into a table for each increment of initial probability. Basically, I am trying to use the second piece of code to fill in the "xxx" for the table. Better?

Comment: @a.powell It's better to modify your question than to put clarifications in comments.

Comment: @Imo I did so. Hope it helps answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you reference are actually in the `binomSamSize` package.  They are vectorized, which makes this a little easier, unless you're providing multiple values to more than one argument.

I used `dplyr` just to make it a little easier to push these into a data frame.

```
library(binomSamSize)
library(dplyr)
p0_vec <- seq(0.8, 0.9, by = 0.02)

rbind(
  ciss.wald(p0=p0_vec, 
            alpha=0.1, 
            d=0.05),
  ciss.agresticoull(p0=p0_vec, 
                    alpha=0.1, 
                    d=0.05),
  vapply(p0_vec,
         ciss.binom,
         numeric(1),
         alpha=0.1, 
         d=0.05,
         prior.shape1 = 0.5,
         prior.shape2 = 0.5, 
         method = "bayes")
) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  bind_cols(
    data.frame(type = c("Wald", "AC", "Jeff"), 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    .
  ) %>%
setNames(c("type", p0_vec))
```